How to Dynamically Select Start and End Times for Flux Query in Grafana?
I'm using InfluxDB to store time-series data and Flux for querying. I have a scenario where I need to dynamically select start and end times based on specific conditions for each sensor and motif. This Flux query is designed to dynamically select start and end times for querying time-series data stored in InfluxDB based on specific conditions for each sensor and motif. The start_time and end_time variables are calculated independently by filtering the data based on sensor name and timestamp values. These variables are then passed into the range() function to filter data within the specified time range.
While the query works as expected in InfluxDB, when integrated into Grafana, it encounters issues. Despite specifying dynamic time range selection in the Flux query, Grafana continues to utilize the default time range set in the dashboard, resulting in discrepancies between expected and actual time ranges used for data visualization. Below is the query:
Query:
start_time = () => {
    timeRecord = from(bucket: "motifs_timestamp")
        |> range(start: 0)
        |> filter(fn: (r) => r["sensor_name"] == "[3:25]")
        |> filter(fn: (r) => r["timestamp"] == "start")
        |> findRecord(fn: (key) => true, idx: 0)
    
    return timeRecord._time
}

end_time = () => {
    timeRecord = from(bucket: "motifs_timestamp")
        |> range(start: 0)
        |> filter(fn: (r) => r["sensor_name"] == "[3:25]")
        |> filter(fn: (r) => r["timestamp"] == "end")
        |> map(fn: (r) => ({_time: r._time}))
        |> findRecord(fn: (key) => true, idx: 0)

    return timeRecord._time
}

from(bucket: "motifs_timestamp")
    |> range(start: start_time(), stop: end_time())
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "motifs_per_signal")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "sensor_reading")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["sensor_name"] == "[3:25]")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["motif_name"] == "Motifs_1")


Any insights or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

You need to extract the times as scalar values from the streams, have a look at Extract scalar values in Flux.

I have modified that query now it works in influxdb but it is not working in Grafana. In Grafana it is still taking the dashboard range instead of the range that I have specified in the query.

I don't think changing time range is possible. It was requested with no follow up yet.

It's an essential requirement in my current project. Are there any workarounds or alternative solutions available?
